# What is protected virtual new

Tags: c#

I was reading a tutorial about making custom principal, and I've encountered the code:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

How exactly is "protected virtual new" working ?

Keyword "new" is what confuses me the most.

Comment: It's covered in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx which should always be your first port of call

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`protected` means that it is visible only inside this class and classes derived from it.

`virtual` means that it can be overriden in derived classes.

`new` means that here you create new overriding hierarchy, i.e. you stop overriding the method defined in the base class and replace it with this method.

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/versioning-with-the-override-and-new-keywords)

Comment: And most of the time it's a bad idea to introduce a `new` member of a class, that hides a member already there (inherited from a base class). Why not just choose another name (than `User`) for the property, one that is not in conflict with a member already there?

Comment: Well, it's kind of pointless to have Controller.User already from the base class and Controller.CustomUser. I like this thing with new, it makes my code clean. Thanks Zdeslav for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 7):

`new` is used for member hiding.

Unlike an overridden method, a `new` method will not be called by a reference to the base class.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

**Your key question:** "Keyword `new` is what confuses me the most."

**Short answer:** `new` and `override` are mutually exclusive. `new` is used to **replace** a class member inherited from a base class. In contrast, `override` is used to **extend** the base class implementation of a member.

From [new Modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) *( Visual Studio 2013)*:

> It is an error to use both **new** and [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) on the same member,
>   because the two modifiers have mutually exclusive meanings. The **new**
>   modifier creates a new member with the same name and causes the
>   original member to become hidden. The **override** modifier extends the
>   implementation for an inherited member.